# How to create a node template for treeview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I want to add a link beside the node text in treeview. like the following figure:

[image]

After some googling, I found that there's no NodeTemplate in the treeview and creating the node text manually like [this sample](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASPNET_TreeView_using_C_.aspx) is the only way.

The only problem I have is that the built-in selection functionality isn't worked anymore, because the internal javascript select function isn't called.

Any idea about a workarround or another way to implement my goal?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried RenderPostText?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treenode.renderposttext.aspx

http://kb.cnblogs.com/a/1379715/